# Autostart VirtualBox on system startup

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, autostart

I am running the latest version of Ubuntu 22.10 and I have installed VirtualBox onto the system.
I am looking for a possibility to start VirtualBox on the system start-up and after that, I want to automatically boot up one VM. but unfortunately I am not a Linux Guru.

I have seen several questions been asked here but every time is see this question asked. but after several explanations of experts there is no reply if it worked.

I have tried some but I haven't still figure it out.
I use the local user that is made from the installation (not root).

Maybe someone can help me with this!

Comment: i have also followed the instructions on the site below : https://www.paulligocki.com/make-virtual-box-vm-autostart/

Comment: Why do i get a negative vote on my post?

Comment: My guess? "I have seen several questions been asked here but every time is see this question asked. but after several explanations of experts there is no reply if it worked." is because of this as it is not how AU works. "there is no reply if it worked" see the checkmark in front of answers and the amount of upvotes on an answer. There is no "it works" reply on AU.  And as you do not list any of these "several explanations of experts" your question seems to lack details. I can guarantee this has been answered before in a way that will work for your question

Comment: Thanks for your explaination. i have tried it sometime and suddenly it works.... ;-)